# Dynamically allocated array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, parameters, heap-memory

I'm learning pointers in but I'm stuck on dynamic allocation of arrays.

The code below provides a function to find the element with the lowest value.
A dynamically allocated array is passed as a parameter to it.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int findMin(int *arr, int n);

int main()
{
    int *nums = new int[5];
    int nums_size = sizeof(*nums);

    cout << "Enter 5 numbers to find the minor:" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < nums_size; i++)
        cin >> nums[i];

    cout << "The minor number is " << findMin(*nums, nums_size);

    delete [] nums; 

    return 0;
}
```

But it return this error:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]
```

How can I pass that array to the function?

Just for curiosity: why the for loop allows me to enter 4 value if my array is made up of 5 elements?

Comment: Notice that the `new` is not needed in this case. You should allocate it on the stack using `int[] nums[5];` instead - it is faster, and doesn't allocate memory on the heap that you need to explicitly delete.

Comment: `*nums` is an `int`. The `*` is part of the type, not of the variable identifier.

Comment: Think if you had written `int* nums = createArray()`.  There's no way to know at compile-time from just a pointer to an integer how many integers it points to.  And maybe you didn't realize that [`sizeof` is a compile-time thing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/195386/why-is-sizeof-called-a-compile-time-operator), not a run-time thing.

Answer (score 9):

> How can I pass that array to the function?

`nums` is already a type `int*`, you don't need to dereference it:

```
findMin(nums, nums_size);
```

> why the for loop allows me to enter 4 value if my array is made up of 5 elements?

`int nums_size = sizeof(*nums);` does not do what you think it does. It's equivalent to `sizeof(nums[0])`, which is equivalent to `sizeof(int)`, which happens to be equal to `4` at your machine.
There is no way to extract size of array allocated on the heap, you need to save the size on your own:

```
int nums_size = 5;
int* nums = new int[nums_size];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int findMin(int *arr, int n){
    int mn=INT_MAX;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(arr[i]<mn){
            mn=arr[i];
        }
    }
    return mn;
};

int main()
{
    int nums_size = 5; 
    int *nums = new int[nums_size];

    cout << "Enter 5 numbers to find the minor:" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < nums_size; i++)
        cin >> nums[i];

    cout << "The minor number is " << findMin(nums, nums_size);

    delete [] nums; 

    return 0;
}
```

The above code works fine. Your error was in passing the array to the function.

Also to add -

Your code made only 4 iterations coz `sizeof(*nums)` returned the size of base index element pointed by pointer, i.e ,sizeof(num[0]). So I made a minor change and now it works fine.

Comment: `sizeof(*nums)` isn't doing what you're describing.

Comment: Try to change `int *nums = new int[5];` to `int *nums = new int[10];` and `sizeof(*nums)` will still be the same (despite larger capacity of array).

Comment: What should I do then?

Comment: @UnoaCaso The program now works fine. I made the edit.

Comment: @Abhishek `for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)`  -- You should always consider it a code smell, if not a mistake, if you're using `<=` as a continue / stop condition in a loop.

Comment: `sizeof(*nums)` also does not return the sizeof of a pointer. `*nums` is no pointer